# My tool bar has disappeared

Tags: desktop-background

My tool bar at the top of the desktop have disappeared.  To be honest it gave an error and when I clicked the error it it disappeared, now I want to get it back.  What should i do?!

I went to Ubuntu software center but I couldn't do anything.

This is a picture of my desktop

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once before. Did you install any new programs or updates, or a new kernel version Here is the answer. "Most possible a bug, sound similar to Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears. Here is the link [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)